# Ingress nginx cache

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to figure out how to use nginx proxy cache with some specific rules. For exemple, when i'm hosting Ghost or Wordpress, I don't want to cache admin section. Using server snippet, I've tried a lot of different combinaison but still have issues with cache in admin section.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |-
  proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
  proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
  proxy_cache app_cache;
  proxy_cache_lock on;
  proxy_cache_valid any 30m;
  add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
```

I want to use nginx code snippet for (ghost|sinout) paths to bypass cache when in admin area, but i'm loosing the proxy_pass context resulting to a 502 bad gateway.

Here is the current ingress config caching every pages, admin path too:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |-
      proxy_cache my_blog_cache;
      proxy_cache_lock on;
      proxy_cache_valid any 30m;
      add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
      proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
  name: my-blog
  namespace: web
spec:
  rules:
  - host: blog.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ingress-541322b8660dbd2ceb1e8ff1813f0dd5
          servicePort: 2368
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - blog.example.com
    secretName: my-blog-cert
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 1.2.3.4
```

Here is the nginx config i'm trying to get but not compatible with ingress annotations:

```
   location / {
        proxy_cache my_blog_cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 30m;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
        proxy_pass http://ghost_upstream;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
        proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
        proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_hide_header X-powered-by;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        expires 10m;
    }
    location /content/images {
        alias /path/to/ghost/content/images;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
    location /assets {
        alias /path/to/ghost/content/themes/uno-master/assets;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
    location /public {
        alias /path/to/ghost/core/built/public;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
    location /ghost/scripts {
        alias /path/to/ghost/core/built/scripts;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
    location ~ ^/(?:ghost|signout) { 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://ghost_upstream;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    }
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some options in nginx-ingress controller that is only possible to change using [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/) and other is possible using [Annnotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/), as you are doing.

You can combine both to reach the expected result, or create a [custom template](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61272743/how-to-set-the-ssl-session-cache-values-in-configmap-kubernetes/61344553#61344553) you can see an alternative that maybe could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using Annotations is quite limited for specific rules and config map impact the whole of your ingresses ? Or maybe there is some way to attach template or configmap to an ingress ? I've found an alternative by creating multiple ingresses with specific annotations for each path location. Ex:
path: / -> Cache applied, cache status = hit
path: /ghost -> No annotations, cache status = missed
And it works ! Is it a good practice ?

Comment: There is no problem create more than one ingress to your application, if all of them get the same IP it would be fine, you just need to take care with the future maintanance... As you said, annottations is a quite limited to cusmotize all nginx, and it is the reason you can choose combine with a nginx template option.

Answer (score 7):

I had exact same desire: cache Ghost responses with respect to their `Cache-Control` headers directly on Nginx Ingress in the Kubernetes cluster.

After some hours spent on it here is my solution:

## First step

First of all, you need to define `proxy_cache_path` on Nginx Ingress [`ConfigMap` level](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/) (the docs are really unclear on how to apply it tbh).

In my case, I manage Nginx Ingress installation via Helm, so I've added it to Helm values chart:

```yaml
# Default values https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml
controller:
  config:
    http-snippet: "proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx_my_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=mycache:2m use_temp_path=off max_size=2g inactive=48h;"
```

Then apply this change:

```
helm upgrade -f my-nginx-ingress-values.yaml ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --recreate-pods
```

## Second step

Now that we have `proxy_cache_path` set, we need to configure Ingress for particular host with annotations:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myingress
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    # Buffering must be enabled for Nginx disk cache to work.
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
    # See https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/
    # Cache Key Zone is configured in Helm config.
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      proxy_cache mycache;
      proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
      proxy_cache_background_update on;
      proxy_cache_revalidate on;
      proxy_cache_lock on;
      add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
```

Note:

> I spent most time figuring out why I was still getting `MISS`es. Turned out it's due to `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering` [default in Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#proxy-buffering) — `off` — this DISABLES Nginx caching, thus you **have** to set it to `on` which is what we do.

Apply the change to Ingress.

## Debugging resulting Nginx config

You can and should I think verify resulting `nginx.conf` used for Ingress that is generated as result of applying `ConfigMap` and Ingress-level annotations.

To do so, you can copy `nginx.conf` from Ingress Controller pod to your local machine and verify its content (or `exec` into pod and see it there):

```
# Make sure to use correct namespace where Ingress Controller is deployed
# and correct Ingress Controller Pod name
kubectl cp -n default ingress-nginx-controller-xxxx:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf ~/Desktop/nginx.conf
```

It should contain all the changes we've made!

## Debugging actual response caching

Now that we have everything configured — it's time to verify actual caching. Note that we have added `X-Cache-Status` header which will indicate if it's a `HIT` or `MISS`.

I personally like [httpie](https://httpie.io/) for HTTP requests from Terminal, you can use `curl` or browser:

First request is going to be `MISS`:

```
http https://example.com/myimage.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 53588
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 10:39:06 GMT
ETag: W/"d154-17c3aa43389"
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Oct 2021 06:56:52 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
X-Cache-Status: HIT
X-Powered-By: Express
X-Request-ID: 0c73f97cb51d3071f14968720a26a99a

+-----------------------------------------+
| NOTE: binary data not shown in terminal |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Second request to same URL is now a `HIT` and doesn't hit the actual Ghost installation, success!

```
http https://example.com/myimage.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 53588
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 10:39:43 GMT
ETag: W/"d154-17c3aa43389"
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Oct 2021 06:56:52 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
X-Cache-Status: HIT
X-Powered-By: Express
X-Request-ID: 0c73f97cb51d3071f14968720a26a99a

+-----------------------------------------+
| NOTE: binary data not shown in terminal |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

It's also useful to verify logs on Ghost to double-check that cache HIT requests actually served directly from Nginx and never hit Ghost.

---